# XNA - How to load the entire content of a .ini file

Tags: c#, xna, ini

I managed to write to and read a specific parameter from a .ini file.
I was wondering if there was a way to load the entire content of the .ini file and store it in a special class. That way, I only have to load the .ini file once. This way it should reduce the amount of loading that the game will do.

I know that in small games, it propably doesn't matter, but I would still appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the INI is a simple key / value pair split with new line could you use something like this to provide the entire INI file as either a dictionary or a strongly typed object.

the  method allows you to load an ini file into an object like this.

```
class IniStructure
{
    public short Field1;
    public int Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
}

IniStructure ini = IniLoader.Load<IniStructure>(<fileName>);
```

or simply in to a dictionary with the non T method.

```
public static class IniLoader
    {
        public static T Load<T>(string fileName)
        {
            T results = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));

            PropertyInfo[] tProperties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
            FieldInfo[] tFields = typeof(T).GetFields();

            var iniFile = Load(fileName);

            foreach (var property in tProperties)
                if (iniFile.ContainsKey(property.Name))
                {
                    object s = System.Convert.ChangeType(iniFile[property.Name].ToString(), property.PropertyType);
                    property.SetValue(results, s, null);
                }
            foreach (var field in tFields)
                if (iniFile.ContainsKey(field.Name))
                {
                    object s = System.Convert.ChangeType(iniFile[field.Name].ToString(), field.FieldType);
                    field.SetValue(results, s);
                }

            return results;
        }

        public static Dictionary<string, object> Load(string fileName)
        {
            Dictionary<string, object> results = new Dictionary<string, object>();

            string fileText = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
            string[] fileLines = fileText.Split('\r');
            if (fileLines.Length > 0)
                for (int i = 0; i < fileLines.Length; i++)
                {
                    string line = fileLines[i].Trim();
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
                    {
                        int equalsLocation = line.IndexOf('=');
                        if (equalsLocation > 0)
                        {
                            string key = line.Substring(0, equalsLocation).Trim();
                            string value = line.Substring(equalsLocation + 1, line.Length - equalsLocation - 1);

                            results.Add(key, value);
                        }
                    }
                }

            return results;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, with a bit of editing, I got it to work as I want it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the creators of C# tend to push people in the direction of XML based config files rather then INI files - so there isn't anything built in. I found this article on CodeProject that wraps things in a nice class. Will this be of any help?

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1966/An-INI-file-handling-class-using-C

I didn't write it - and am not taking credit for it, but it may be what you are looking for :)

Comment: Yes, I was already using this. :) But you can only load specific keys and not the entire file. I want to read out the entire and store in in a class to save loading time, when my game increases size.

Comment: Right, then the answer Andy posted below is a better way of doing things. May i ask why you chose ini files over XML? C# already supports serializing/deserializing objects into XML - something along these lines: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-xml-serialization

Comment: Well, I am not that good in game development, so I though to use different kind of files for different kind of data to get used to using different file types. I am going to use .ini files for settings, .scv files for localization and .xml for large quantities of text. i know it may not be the best way to do things, but I think it is a great way to learn o understand how things works with different kind of file types.

Comment: Ah i see, i think it's a good idea actually, nothing like learning something new! :)